# How to maintain value for every user connected inside socket events

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, events, io

I have a question. I'm new to nodejs so don't judge :D.
So let me explain what i want to do. 
I want to make a game where the server is written in nodejs. I'm using sockets and events. 
My question is this: When i connect for the first time to the server i'm using the variable currentUser to store current user conntected information(name espacialy), but when another user connects, everything that is inside currentUser gets wiped for every other user besides him. For example 3 users connects: aaa,bbb,ccc. When aaa connects, currentuser for aaa will store the name aaa. When bbb connects the information in currentUser for aaa gets wiped and the value is undifened and currentUser for bbb will store the name bbb. The same for ccc. currentUser for aaa and bbb will have the value undifined and for ccc will store the name ccc;
Is there a way to store the name for every user and keep it inside the io.on("connection",) and not globally?

```
const express=require('express');
const app=express();

const server=require('http').createServer(app);
const io=require('socket.io').listen(server);

app.set('port',process.env.PORT || 3000);

let socketUsers={};
let usersON={};

io.on("connection",function(socket){

    socket.on("CONNECTION",function(){

        socket.emit("CONNECTION_ON");

    });

    let currentUser;
    let partenerUser;

    socket.on("USER_ON",function(data){

        if(usersON[data.name]==null)
        {
            this.currentUser={
                name:data.name,
                status:data.status,
                position:"0;0;0"
            };
            process.stdout.write("User \""+data.name+"\" ,status("+data.status+") CONNECTED. \n");

            socket.emit("ONLINE_USERS",usersON);
            socket.emit("USER_OK");

            usersON[data.name]=data.status;

            socketUsers[data.name]=socket;



            socket.broadcast.emit("NEW_USER_CONNECTED",this.currentUser.name);


        }
        else
        {
            process.stdout.write("User \""+data.name+"\" ,status("+data.status+") EXISTS. \n");

            socket.emit("USER_EXISTS");

        }

    });
    socket.on("USER_SEARCH",function(data){

        console.log(this.currentUser);
        console.log(usersON);
        console.log("----------------");
        console.log(usersON[data.name]);
        console.log(data.name.toString());
        console.log(this.currentUser);
        console.log(currentUser);

       if(usersON[data.name]!=null && socketUsers[data.name]!=null && this.currentUser.name!==data.name.toString())//utilizatorul exista
       {
            console.log(usersON[data.name]);

           if(usersON[data.name]!=="OFF")
           {
               io.to(socketUsers[data.name].id).emit("USER_WANTTOPLAY",currentUser);// =? do you want to play?
               socket.emit("WAIT_RESPONSE");
           }
           else
           {
               socket.emit("USER_OFF");
           }
       }
       else
           {
           socket.emit("USER_NOTFOUND");// => INSERT OTHER username
       }
    });
    socket.on("USER_WANTTOPLAY",function(data){
        console.log("AICI");
        this.partenerUser={
            name:data.name,
            status:data.status,
            position:"0;0;0"
        }
    });
    socket.on("RESPONSE_OK",function(data){

        io.to(socketUsers[partenerUser.name].id).emit('RESPONSE_YYES');
    });
    socket.on("RESPONSE_NO",function(data){

        io.to(socketUsers[partenerUser.name].id).emit('RESPONSE_NNO');
    });
});

server.listen(app.get('port'),function(){
    console.log("=========SERVER IS RUNNING=========");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you define the variable `currentUser`, but not using it. You're using `this.currentUser` which is not the variable you have defined.

`this` in that context references `io` object, which is the same for every connection, that's why `this.currentUser` is changing on every connection.

use

```
currentuser = { /* ... */ };
```

instead of

```
this.currentuser = { /* ... */ };
```

And the same goes for `partnerUser`.

An alternative is to store the data directly on the current `socket` object, and to avoid collisions use a **[Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol)**

```
// This will be unique to your app. Won't collide with socket.io properties
const USER = Symbol('user'); 
const PARTNER = Symbol('partner');

io.on("connection", function(socket) {

  socket.on("CONNECTION", function() {
    socket.emit("CONNECTION_ON");
  });

  socket.on("USER_ON", function(data) {
    if (usersON[data.name] == null) {
      socket[USER] = {  // Add data to current socket.
        name: data.name,
        status: data.status,
        position: "0;0;0"
      };
    }
    /* ... */
  });

  socket.on("USER_SEARCH", function(data) {
    console.log(socket[USER]); // Current user
  });

  /* ... */
});
```

Comment: I removed ,, .this,, but is the same. Same errors. Your solution is ok but is not what i want. Now i did find the cause of the problem and i'm trying to find out why is this happening. So for every user a connection is established, but i don't know why, when another user connects, the last one it's resetting all the other old sockets.

Comment: What variable is being resetted? Can you specify please. Because my solution works perfectly, I'm using it in multiple apps, you're probably doing something else, because if you save the data to the current socket, it cannot be overriden by other socket.

Comment: My problem is that a new socket is reasign to every user connected, when a new user connects. Look at this output: https://imgur.com/slE4SyK . I printed the socket id for 3 users connecting in this order: aaa - first, bbb- second, ccc- third. After all of them are connected, in the same order i'm searching (triggering the search event) for a ,,user,, in USERLIST (users ,,on,, on the server). You can see that the socket.id changed, and only for the last user connected is the same

Comment: Sorry but that screenshot tells me absolutely nothing, you're attempting to do something in an incorrect way, how do you reassign a new socket to every user connected, what are you trying to achieve? Seriously explain yourself correctly, and update yo question, my answer is the solution you need, you're using it wrong.